# database design primary key of multiple tables link to one table

Tags: sql, database-design

I have 4 tables.

```
server : serial_number{PK}, host_name
printer : serial_number{PK}, host_name
VM : host_name{PK}
ip_address : host_name{PK}, ip_address{PK} (composite key)
```

server, printer and VM tables one-to-many ip_address tables.
I link them up by host_name.

Is this correct?

To make my question more clear, what I have now is

> server  1--------* ip_address 
>   printer 1--------* ip_address 
>   VM      1--------* ip_address

host_name of each table will be different.

[image]

Comment: Please describe your problem in detail. What did you try? I don't get why you need a table VM with only one column. Give more details.

Comment: VM table has many columns but I just put the necessary one here. Each server, printer and VM may have more than one ip address. So I have one ip_address table to insert each device's ip addresses. Do you get what I mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As server and printer tables have same structure, I would suggest to have a single table to store the host name with hardware_type column to distinguish the hardware. We can have another table to store the mapping of device type and device name.

Also, if vm table has the same structure (?) we can merge that table too in the master table.

Structure of ip_address can be altered based on whether host name can be unique or not. Need to have the full structures to elaborate more.

Comment: They do not have the same structure. So I cannot merge them.

Comment: Two servers/printers may have same host name. In this case, we need to have some mechanism to check which host name belongs to which server. Hence, I would suggest to have device_type (server/printer/vm) and serial_number in the ip address table to distinguish, but again, vm table does not have serial_number column. Is it possible to alter the structure of any of these 3 tables?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I added in device_type in ip_address table. host_name will be unique. So no worry about that. What I understand is that - if server table link to ip_address table, ip_address.host_name is FK. And printer table link to ip_address table, ip_address.host_name is FK. That means ip_address.host_name value must be in server and printer table. Am I right? I do not want this case because host_name of server and printer is unique.

Comment: Yes. In that case, host name needs to be present in both the tables. As host name itself is unique, I don't think serial number is required. Host name itself can serve as primary key.